# How to make a LogLinearPlot out of an Histogram?

Tags: plotting

I want to make a histogram with a logarithmic x-axis, like the one produced by `LogLinearPlot`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
Histogram[c, "Log", Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]